# How could this ever be true?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy

I am new here. Infact I got an account here to genuinely find an answer, how could all this be true right at the very beginning? Pardon my mistakes because I am not jewish. Apologies in advance if I don't address GOD or other important figures with right reverence. If we go back few years, we know for a fact, from the WW2 records and other historical record about certain ruthless dictator committing crimes against Jews. We know such a person existed. On a brighter side, King David, we have his tomb till this day so we know he existed. But if we go several centuries back, things get blurry. How do we know that the red sea was parted and Israelites walked through it, or, the sun was delayed from setting so the battle could go on and the Israelites could win, or when Moses put his staff down, it turned into a snake. That is absolutely not possible at all. Earth is round. I can imagine localized flooding in a low lying region such as New Orleans, but Noah was in the Middle east. Looking at the earth from the space station and imagining forty days of rain and flood waters rising will cause the ocean to over flow. It cannot rain every where at the same time. Flood was probably localized perhaps and human race on eastern hemisphere was not destroyed perhaps?  There are several things which are absolutely impossible. The donkey talking to Balaam/Balaak. Or Prophet Lots wife turning into a pillar of salt. Or the pillar of cloud and fire. I know the easy answer is "GOD". But then, if He broke the laws of physics/nature back then, why is He silent know. Leads me to wonder if all this is really true? Sorry I don't mean to offend any one. Its easy to believe all these people did exist, but certain hyperbolic things never ever happened

Comment: For the record, many if not all of the examples you mention are interpreted by some rabbis as not happening literally.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I think, at the core, you're asking "how can all this be true?".  I've marked your question as a duplicate of another that asks that; check out the answers there.  [This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/56703/472) is also related.  if your question is different, you can [edit] to explain how and we'll review it for possible reopening.  If you haven't already, please check out our short [tour] that explains more about how the site works.  Thanks.

Comment: @R.Indu I think this is a great question, and that a classic Jewish book called The Kuzari has your answer

Comment: Thank you all for your replies and answers. @SAH I will get hold of that book. Thanks

Comment: For questions you might be thinking about asking--they might be here, sometimes downvoted, but so what--they're genuine curiosity questions from a non-Jew and valuable, check out our friend J. Chang's questions and their answers.

Comment: Please see my answer [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/110675/19691) regarding the pillar of clouds