# How do we answer those who claim G-d doesn't exist?

Tags: theology

How do we counter the claims from atheists and doubters that there is no proof G-d exists, and claim the Torah was written by a bunch of little old Jewish guys. Is there a source that can provide a definitive argument that G-d exists and here is why, other than "I believe with perfect faith," etc.

Comment: [Spurious](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spurious)?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8231/472

Comment: Related to your question: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PEg_Oys4NkA

Is there a rational basis to believe that Judaism is true? In this lecture, Lawrence Kelemen presents a rational approach to the Divine origin of Judaism. You will find out the one unique claim that Judaism makes that no other religion in history has made.