# infallible reasoning for believing in a god that created and runs the world

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, theology, faith-bitachon-emunah

In the Torah it is written that we should serve God, love him, have trust in him, believe that he runs the show and in return we are promised a share in the world to come - a world of eternal bliss.

Is there any infallible evidence that there is indeed an all powerful supreme supernatural creator and that the Torah is divine?

There are proofs such as the exact number of minimum days in the renewal of the moon, all fish with scales also have fins, codes in the torah, etc.

However such attempts can backfire with a bit of research in modern science and history.

Is there any way one can know without any doubts whatsoever that there is a God and that he runs the show or is there always an element of faith that is involved in the service of God.

Are there any books that one can look up to get more insight in this topic?

Comment: ..."or is there always an element of faith that is involved in the service of god in the ..... religion." Well put! You can substitute pretty much ANY religion for "Jewish" in that sentence...

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/8231/472

Comment: @Shokhet Although the last line is not a dupe.

Comment: I don't feel that it's a duplicate - that question asks how do we know, this questions asks for infallible reasoning for this knowledge.

Answer (score -1):

Of course there is not, if there'll be how could you call it faith and the whole concept of reward and punishment will fall apart

Comment: can you source that? (if you want to do so, perhaps the beis halevi at the end of parshas bo, or avi ezri to hil. teshuva 5:5, though none of them say it quite like that). I think all of the rishonim who attempted to discuss proofs of god disagree though

Comment: Don't have it by me, not anywhere close to beis ha midrash.

Comment: What do you mean? Where would you look?

Comment: Chovot Halevavot mentioned one book in notes, but i don't know where at all, and don't have access to any non-familiar books at home, so I am sorry for not bringing the source but in short that was the explanation for this question.

Comment: Firstly, please don't say "of course not..." when quoting a note to the Chovos Halevavos, where the Chovos Halevavos himself disagrees. Second, I assume you're referring to the lengthy intro of the לב טוב, and I don't think he quotes anyone who says that exactly, but R. Tzvi Elimelech miDinov does say something like it

Comment: I remember what I saw there, ok?! No, i don't refer to the intro of Lev Tov, but to the underline notes, don't have time to go over the whole book.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19653/discussion-between-havarka-and-matt).