# What are the evidence of red/reed sea crossing?

Tags: history, beshalach, yetziat-mitzrayim

Are there any credible historical evidences behind red/reed sea crossing? Besides, of course, the Torah.

Comment: The body of your question contains... no question. Just a link to one, and some meta information. I'm closing this: it can be reopened if improved.

Comment: Anyway, it's pretty much a duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/124/archeological-proof-of-exodus

Comment: Oh, good point, @IsaacMoses. It is. Never mind, then: I guess I won't reopen it after all.

Comment: Not really duplicate. That question ask about exodus in general. I am asking about the red sea. Any mass chariots on the same era on a sea would work. Large number of skeletons on desert having jewish DNA would work too (but that would be for the 40 years wandering in the desert). I like to examine problem one at a time rather than in general.

Comment: Okay, good point. Reopening. I've edited out all the meta stuff, which included the link to a previous version of this question: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/832/what-are-the-historical-evidence-of-israels-crossing-of-red-sea

Comment: I think the fact that people in history channel think there is no evidence should be mentioned. Certain facts are so politically incorrect it won't be mainstream. Even when there is no factual controversy people would deliberately create controversy when they don't like it and deliberately create certainty on dubious fact they like. Evolution vs creationism is one such thing. I know many things far worse I wouldn't ask here :). Still like having friends here.

Comment: As this stackexchange deals in traditional Judaism and not archaeology, is this an answerable question within the context of the site?  The answer is that the Torah is the evidence.  Three million Jewish eyewitnesses are the evidence.  This is obviously not the answer the OP has in mind, but it is the correct answer in the context of this site.

Comment: That's all you got isn't it?

Comment: Even if that's all we got, that's still a good start. For example, there is a claim that no one else will make a similar claim. That part I can ask in history channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no definitive evidence of the crossing of Yam Suf.  This if or a couple of reasons.

1. There is disagreement about which body of water is called "Yam Suf"
2. There is disagreement about what sort of evidence would prove that "Yam Suf" happened.  The reason for this is that the Midrashim creates many stories with conflicting information as to what we should expect to look for. For example, are we looking for 12 paths, that return back to the same shore, or 1 path that leads to the other side of the yam? Are we looking for evidence of plants and bread being grown into the ocean walls?  Are we looking for Egyptian armor and tools, or did those wash ashore to the Israelites for them to use in the war with Amalek later on?

However, there is a person who has created a video which you can find online, which claims to have found wheels and axles of Egyptian chariots in a body of water near egypt and some high cliffs.  I'm not linking to it, because I don't think this person needs links to their site.

Interestingly, there are also [some computer models](http://www2.ucar.edu/news/2663/parting-waters-computer-modeling-applies-physics-red-sea-escape-route) that show how a eastern wind could split the sea in a specific part of the Nile Delta, which until now has not been considered as a location for the crossing.

Neither the computer models, nor the research of the guy in the video I mentioned above count as 'credible evidence' in most people's minds.

Comment: Well, evidence is different than proof. In a sense, you can't really proof anything. You can only do that in Math. Every evidence is a precious peace of a puzzle. That's good enough.

Comment: That computer generated evidence do not fit the description that israel see water in their left and right like wall. But a good model. Perhaps if the same computer model is generated on location of the chariots?

Comment: Something I have learned from archaeological digs here in Israel, is that how we imagine things to look when described a certain way, do not at all match how things looked 2,000 years ago. I'm not so sure that a "wall" was anything more than a small rising that was knee high.  You say wall and I picture something at least 8 feet high.  But if you look at some old walls, they can sometimes only be 1 or 2 feet high.  (Make's the laws of sukkoth a bit more understandable btw.)

Comment: Also, regarding the computer model at a different location. The reason why the wind works there is because you have 3 different sources of water converging on the same point.  The wind is able to push back the water towards it's source. (the Nile, the Mediteranean, and the lake)  Some spot in the middle of the ocean, especially a deep spot, would not  be capable of splitting like that. Atleast according to the computer model.

Comment: yes the sea cannot be too deep. I think I saw a site where a sea that looks like river can also split with correct wind.