# Critical Jewish analysis of the Ipuwer papyrus

Tags: history, yetziat-mitzrayim, plagues-makkos, shemot-exodus, archaeology

I just stumbled across information about the [Ipuwer papyrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipuwer_papyrus), and I was wondering how many Jewish Egyptologists have had an opportunity to review and study it at length. Other than [this very brief analysis by R' Mordechai Becher](http://ohr.edu/838), and the article cited therein, are there any more recent, and more comprehensive, analyses of the document and its (possible) relationship to [the Exodus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Exodus)?

Comment: Are you looking specifically for a Jewish Egyptologist, or just an Egyptologist aware of Jewish sources?

Comment: I don't think this guy is Jewish or an Egyptologist, but his footnotes might head in the correct direction.  http://www.henryzecher.com/papyrus_ipuwer.htm

Comment: The ohr.edu page mentions another article, which can be found [here](http://www.ou.org/chagim/pesach/whenex.htm)

Comment: Does Dr. Immanuel Velikovsky count (he wasn't an Egyptologist and he's not more recent, but he did write quite comprehensively about it)?

Answer (score 5):

Check out http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=676 חלק א . By the way - read the rest of the book too. It is amazing.

Comment: ykay, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for sharing this source and recommendation! Your answer would be more valuable if you'd include the title and author of the book you're pointing to as well as a description of what it discusses regarding the topic at hand (and parenthetically, to back up your recommendation, what the rest of the book is about). Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.