# Did Mitzri documents ever mention Yetzias Mitzraim?

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim

Are there any Egyptian writings/sources from the time of Yetzias Mitzraim that mention the Makkos?

Comment: http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/564/do-any-egyptian-hieroglyphics-mention-the-ten-plagues

Comment: Remember that ancient historians were not as honest as our modern ones. If they didn't like an aspect of their history, they changed it or even left it out of historical records. I don't remember where right now but I believe the Greeks wrote in their history books that they won certain wars when in actuality they lost.

Comment: @ezra Amazing, isn't it, that they convinced whole nations of people of these falsehoods.

Answer (score 0):

Rav Avigdor Miller in his commentary on Shemos, *A Nation Is Born*, seems to make a connection between the Ipuwer Papyrus throughout his elaboration of the makkos. For instance, he quotes the Ipuwer on page 83 when discussing the first makkah as well as page 103 when discussing the seventh makkah.

> p.83 Ipuwer wrote: "The river is blood....Blood is everywhere..Men
>   shrink from tasting...that is our water...what shall we do? Everything
>   is in ruination?" 
>   p.103 The Ipuwer Papyrus declares: "Gates, columns, and walls are
>   consumed by fire. The sky is in confusion. It almost destroyed
>   mankind."

Comment: This Christian site does present an interesting collection of passages from that document. However, the Wikipedia page linked, and all of the links from there that are relevant to this question dispute the validity of this connection. I have to -1 unless better indication is provided that this is historical and related to the events of _Sh'mos_.

Comment: Your first source is a Christian site. Your second source (Wikipedia) discredits this as proof: Ipuwer and the Book of ExodusEdit

The archeological evidence does not support the story of the Exodus, and most histories of ancient Israel no longer consider it relevant.[10][11]

Comment: Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13480/759